# Citation for biprofunctor

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Does anyone know a book or article in a journal that defines *biprofunctors* between bicategories $\Bbb A$ and $\Bbb B$, as in [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/finnlawler/show/biprofunctor), i.e., as a pseudo functor $\Bbb A^{op}\times\Bbb B\to\Bbb C\rm{at}$? Perhaps it also exists under some other name, that I'm not familiar with..

I prefer not to refer only the nLab webpage..

Comment: It looks like this is part of [Finn Lawler's thesis outline](http://ncatlab.org/finnlawler/show/thesis+--+preliminaries). Did you contact [him](https://www.cs.tcd.ie/~flawler/)?

Comment: Not yet. Good idea, thanks.
But, perhaps it also exists under some other name.

Comment: In my (still!) unfinished PhD thesis, I used to call your "biprofunctors" Cat-valued profunctors/distributors/modules, or just Cat-profunctors. Another closely related concept is "2-discrete fibred span".

Comment: I posted an [answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/392809) for a related question.